# How do I create cold replay observable from a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I want my service (angular, typeScript, rxjs5) to return an observable rather than a promise.

I need this observable:

1. to start cold (if no one subscribed, don’t hit the server)
2. to cache the last result forever (it never completes, but if you subscribe late you get the last answer, like replaySubject)
3. to be created/hold value of a promise (my api service returns a promise)

got to this:

```
const deferredObservable = Rx.Observable
  .defer(() => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(this.getFromServer()))
  .replay(true, 1);
```

but nothing happens when I subscribe. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does `replay` come from? It's not an operator. Did you mean `publishReplay()` or `shareReplay()`? http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Comment: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html#collapseRxJS